# Servicio SOAP cambia de https a http

Tags: php, soap, soapui

Hola estoy consumiendo un WS que la url es: https:// myqs.com?wsdl

con el siguiente codigo:

```
$servicio="https://myapp.com/ws.svc?wsdl";
$opt = array('encoding' => 'UTF-8');
$parametros=array(
    'c' => 'a',
    'd' => 'b',
    'e' => 'c'
);

$client = new SoapClient($servicio,$opt);

$result = $client->autentifica($parametros);

 var_dump($result);
```

Ahora cuando abro en el navegador, me muestra un error

```
fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\ws\index.php:50 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://myapp...', 'http://tempuri....', 1, 0) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ws\index.php(50): SoapClient->__call('autentifi...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ws\index.php on line 50
```

En el error me esta indicando existe error en http://myapp y cuando es https://myapp... la url del servicio por que pasara eso? donde?, por que el servicio si esta bien, he testeado con SOAP UI.

Estoy utilizando PHP 7.2

Comment: si tu servicio es http e intentas llegar por https te da el error es por seguridad

Comment: haber el servicio web SOAP que deseo consumir esta en https, pero lo deseo consumir desde un http desde un servidor web local

Comment: vas a tener problemas de seguridad porque alli te pueden robar informacion

Comment: claro, obviando el tema de la seguridad? como podría hacer para poderlo consumir? :-(